# Queryable<T>.Union behaviour in EFCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In order to achieve the equivalent to TSQL `UNION`:

```
SELECT Blogid, Url
FROM Blogs
UNION (SELECT Blogid, Url
        FROM Blogs)
ORDER BY url
```

I've tried to use `Queryable.Union<T>` ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049(v=vs.110).aspx)) and the output to the "end user" is the same, yet when using the `SQL Server Profiler` I can see **two queries** to the same table.

eg (output from SQL Profiler):

Using EFCore

```
SELECT [b1].[BlogId], [b1].[Url]
FROM [Blogs] AS [b1]
go
SELECT [b2].[BlogId], [b2].[Url]
FROM [Blogs] AS [b2]
go
```

'vs'

Query on Management Studio

```
SELECT Blogid, Url
FROM Blogs
UNION (SELECT Blogid, Url
        FROM Blogs)
ORDER BY url
```

According to [this blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-4-query-methods)

> EF translates Union to Union ALL with SELECT DISTINCT, so eventually each result is unique.

The Core for the query in the EF is the following:

```
DbSet<Blog> set = db.Set<Blog>();
List<Tuple<string,int>> blogs = set.Union(set).OrderBy(blog => blog.Url).ToList();
```

Notice that `Union` is not translated, nor is `GroupBy`.
Using the `GroupBy` without `Union`, makes the query be translated to

```
SELECT [blog].[Url] , [blog].[BlogId] 
FROM [Blogs] AS [blog]
ORDER BY [Url]
```

which is the expected behaviour.
Why isn't `Union` being translated correctly?

Comment: On a side note to my answer below, EF Core is not yet feature complete to the legacy EF. It's a complete rewrite of the framework and a few things act differently by design (entity tracking) and others are just not yet completed. So don't expect EF Core to behave exactly the same as the old EF did and don't use it if you don't know the implications of doing so (and that many features have been or still are at the time of this writing, done in memory and not on the server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked article describes this behavior, you just overlooked it.

> EF Core supports Union for entity and primitive types **locally**.

The **EMPHASIS** lies on the word **locally**. Many of the EF Core Linq operators such as GroupBy etc. are not yet translated to SQL as of EF Core 2.0. That being said, any group by operation will be performed in memory in EF Core 2.0 or lower.

The translated query in the article is about EF (the old .NET Framework based EntityFramework 6.x). Also please note the MSDN link in your question is for the old EntityFramework (up to 6.x). EF Core is usually on learn.microsoft.com domain.

EF Core 2.1 will improve many of the missing translations. Have a look at the [EF Core 2.1 Roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/02/entity-framework-core-2-1-roadmap/) and of course at [2.1 Milestone on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/milestone/37) to see the improvements in detail.

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6812) which covers the server-sided translation of Union/Except/Intersect/Concat Linq Operators.

Its labeled as "punted-for-2.1". So it may come to EF Core 2.1, if the time allows it to be completed in the timeframe before EF Core 2.1 gets released otherwise it will be in one of the next releases.

Comment: I read the _locally_ but did not really understand what he meant by locally
So basically, there's no other way to perform a Union without being on the c# side, correct? At least not for now, maybe on 2.1, is that it? 
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Exactly. Unless you're comfortable using EF Core 2.1 [nightly builds](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore) or wait till/if a preview comes to the official feed (not sure about it, but ASP.NET Core 2.1/.NET Core 2.1 previews are expected in March and one preview per month until release)

Comment: The dependencies suggest that EF Core 2.1 doesn't depend on .NET Standard 2.1, so you may just as good be able to use it. Up to you if you want/dare to use it for production applications though. But keep in mind it may not yet be in the preview as its marked punted

Comment: When using the `Union` on Queryable, even the `Where` "moves" to be performed on the c# side, making the request to the database be without any restriction... So basically operators like this one shouldn't be used?

Comment: Yeah, well. But its not easy to know which query gets evaluated on client and which on server side. By default EF Core logs a warning on client sided evaluation. Look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) to see how you can make to throw exception. If course if the returned data is an entity you can always execute a raw query such as `dbContext.Blog.FromSql("your custom query in here")`. With EF Core 2.1 its possible to do ad-hoc model binding from `FromSql` (binding to a model that's not configured as entity of the DbContext)